# Create a random list from 0-100 with different lengths using a class and return the generated list

Tags: python, list, random

I want to generate a list from 0-100 but my criteria is as follows:

1. The list must start with 0 and end with 0.
2. No 0 in between.
3. Different lengths

by far i did this:

```
    import random
    class getRandomSolution:
        ls=[]
        def getsolution(self):
            ls=random.sample(range(100),random.randrange(0,99))
            ls.append(0)
            ls.insert(0,0)
             print('the path/solutuin : {}'.format(ls))
        def parsesoluotion(self):
            return ls



       obj1=getRandomSolution()
       obj1.getsolution()
```

Output:

```
      the path/solutuin : [0, 16, 25, 80, 43, 81, 9, 50, 95, 70, 31, 62, 21, 83, 0]
```

but once i call parsesoluotion method from getRandomSolution class, i get this error:

```
           list1=obj1.parsesoluotion()

            NameError: name 'ls' is not defined
```

Comment: Is any length valid?

Comment: Would love to see your efforts here. What have you done to solve your homework so far?

Comment: @DanielMesejo the maximum length should not exceed 100

Comment: @loyalTurkman Sorry, why should we help you then?

Comment: Well, I'd imagine that's what we'll do to answer your question too...

Comment: @tleb i'm still new at this dude, so help me if you can

Comment: The principle of SO is that you come to the community with a problem you have tried to solve and we point you to a solution/what blocks you. We cannot/aren't supposed to start from scratch at your place.

Comment: @coldspeed i tried using shuffle but it was worthless, my level in python is far from beginner, so help me if you can .

Comment: Stack Overflow is all about helping people who've tried helping themselves. If you're not willing to put in that initial effort to solve your problem, then why should we? We are all unpaid volunteers here, not sweatshop workers for free labour, so please do respect our time, thank you :-)

Comment: @loyalTurkman please (re) read the help page: **"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."** (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers could you help now?

Comment: @loyalTurkman well yes: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

To give you a few hints, you will want to use the random package (I've included a link to the docs below) to first generate a number between 0 - 100

```
random.randint(0, 100)
```

This will then be the size of your list.
Now initialize an empty list, check if size of list is 0 else, append 0 to it.
Then you want to initialize a for loop through to two less than the size of the list (the randomly generated integer) and append random integers (that aren't zero) to the list for the duration of the for loop.

After the for loop is finished, append one more 0 and that should make your required list.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: Please do not answer homework questions that show absolutely no effort and no intention to do any effort.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers There's a reason I wrote it in words rather than code, but I see your point - was just trying to be nice.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i just added my work, there's no reason to be rude, this is my seconded question on SO, have a little mercy.

Comment: @loyalTurkman i've not been rude anywhere, I just posted a couple reminders about SO rules (which you're supposed to have read before posting). Now __you__, when asked " What have you done to solve your homework so far", you explicitely answered : "absolutely nothing", and __this__ is "being rude".

Comment: i guess you're right, ill be better next time, sorry ^_^